# Accept cookies consent from Youtube

Tags: python, cookies, youtube, gdprconsentform

I'm trying to retrieve a list of Youtube videos from a Youtube channel, say "https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube/videos", to get the nth first videos (thanks to the `key = "videoId"`).
It used to work like a charm until a few days ago, when it started to ask for my consent.

I tried many things on SO with no luck, I still see the message asking me to accept the cookies in order to see the videos.

```
import requests
import re

url='https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube/videos'
s1 = requests.session()
s1.get(url)
print("Original Cookies")
print(s1.cookies)
cookieValueNum = (re.findall(r'\d+', str(s1.cookies)))[0]
cookieValue = ('YES+cb.20210328-17-p0.en-GB+FX+'+str(cookieValueNum))
cookie = {'name': 'CONSENT', 'value': cookieValue, 'domain': '.youtube.com'}
print("==========")
print("After new Cookie added")
s1.cookies.update(cookie)
print(s1.cookies)
print(s1.get(url, cookies=cookie).text)
```

It still returns the same message asking my consent for cookies (in html obviously, this is a picture of what I get when opening Youtube in a private session):

[image: YT Consent]

My idea was then to replicate the `Consent` cookie and sent it back to be able to access the page content.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
The idea is not to use the Youtube API but only request/BeautifulSoup if needed.

Comment: Can u share the channel id cause  I tried with this [code](https://codeshare.io/2Kzdvo) and  I am able to get all 30 the ids when calling this channel video URL for example this URL [https://www.youtube.com/user/videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/videos) no consent stuff I got access to json data follow this [code](https://codeshare.io/2Kzdvo) and see if it goes through or share the channel id where you getting the error.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that consent message stuff in my browser or else would have done something by looking at network requests. Edited Can you share the country of ip address you accessing so i could try via proxy of that country and see I get same consent message or no.

Comment: damn I used France IP from ipvanish and even used incognito so no cookies would be sent then also it directly redirected me to video page no sign of consent message like yours.

Comment: Try to disable cookies at all.

Comment: @Öskå Problem in your post example that you don't delete first response cookies, but update them. I'm not sure how to do that, but `requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube/videos', cookies={'CONSENT': 'PENDING+999'})` works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to delete first response cookies. I'm not sure how to do that in requests.session, but any of the following works for me.

```
requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube/videos', cookies={'CONSENT': 'PENDING+999'})

requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube/videos', cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+cb.20210328-17-p0.en-GB+FX+{}'.format(random.randint(100, 999))})
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem - here's a solution that should work just fine for your case.

with browsers like chrome you can always check what data you need to pass to acccept cookies. you find these information in dev tools -> application -> cookies.

[screenshot of the google chrome cookie view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQt0Z.png)

doing this, you'll see that youtube expects YES or NO and any integer > 0.

pass these information in your request. and that's it.

```
requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube/videos', cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+1'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is a hazzle and tries to identify you with those technices. There seems now way around as to keep the consent cookie - or you have to give consent every time

Answer (score 0):

set headers of your request like that:

```
headers = {
        'Authorization': 'authorization',
        'cookie': 'hl=en'
    }
```

And use tor to change your ip on all requests.
after send request check your response, if Before you continue exist in response.text , set time sleep for a few seconds (in this time your ip will be change) and then send request again.