# Python scraping too slow on youtube title from URL - html-render

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

hi i have excel files with youtube url list which i m trying to get their titles as it's full lists of 1000's url's with 3 excel file i tried to work with python  but it comes to be too slow as i had to put sleep command on html render codes are like that :

```
 import xlrd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from xlutils.copy import copy
from requests_html import HTMLSession



loc = ("testt.xls")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
wb2 = copy(wb)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

for i in range(3,sheet.nrows):


    ytlink = (sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    session = HTMLSession()
    response = session.get(ytlink)
    response.html.render(sleep=3)
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    print(ytlink)
    element = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "lxml")
    media = element.select_one('#container > h1').text
    print(media)
    s2 = wb2.get_sheet(0)
    s2.write(i, 0, media)
    wb2.save("testt.xls")
```

I mean is there anyway to make it faster i tried selenium but it was slower i guess. and with this html.render i seem to need to use "Sleep" timer or else it gives me error i tried lower values on sleep but it gets error after a while on lower sleep values any help please thanks :)

ps: prints i put are just for checking the output and such not important on usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 1000 requests in less than a minute using async requests-html like this:

```py
import random
from time import perf_counter
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9eoubnO-pE'] * 1000

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
start = perf_counter()

async def fetch(url):
    r = await asession.get(url, cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+cb.20210328-17-p0.en-GB+FX+{}'.format(random.randint(100, 999))})
    return r

all_responses = asession.run(*[lambda url=url: fetch(url) for url in urls])
all_titles = [r.html.find('title', first=True).text for r in all_responses]

print(all_titles)
print(perf_counter() - start)
```

Done in 55s on my laptop.

Note that you need to pass `cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+cb.20210328-17-p0.en-GB+FX+{}'.format(random.randint(100, 999))}` to the request to avoid [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934826/accept-cookies-consent-from-youtube).

Comment: tried it and it worked faster than before in a for loop to get each url in excel row of that column and replace it with title of that youtube url thanks :) codes are below for informing newbies like myself :

Answer (score 2):

Using your current method/Selenium you are rendering the actual webpage, which you don't need to do. I recommend using a Python library that will handle it for you. Below is an example of YoutubeDL:

```
with YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    title = ydl.extract_info("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw", download=False).get("title", None)
    print(title)
```

Note that doing 1000 of these requests, with the rate limits imposed by YouTube, will still be slow. If you are planning on doing possibly thousand**s** of requests in the future I recommend looking into [getting an API key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

Comment: Oh i saw this but i thought only with api token key i could use it. I guess rate limits can slow it down but it would be still faster than previous method i guess right? as long as its not timed out or something in the middle of excel and make me start over i would be fine with little bit slowiness. As it seems no other way to take without api or render Thanks for the help i will try that :)